# Is there a way to use multiprocessing in a user defined class on another user defined class to modify one of its attributes in place?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to do something like the following:

```
import multiprocessing as mp 
class X:
    def __init__(self,num):
        self.num = num
    def add(self):
        self.num += 1
    def add_arg(self, num):
        self.num+= num
        
    def extra_fancy_add(self, arg1, arg2):
        self.num += arg1/arg2
        
class Y:
    def __init__(self, X):
        self.X = X
    
    def add_all(self):
        with mp.Pool(processes=8) as pool:
            pool.starmap(X.add, [i for i in self.X])

    def fancy_add(self,num):
        with mp.Pool(processes=8) as pool:
            pool.starmap(X.add_arg, [(i, num) for i in self.X])

    def extra_fancy_add(self,num, num2):
        with mp.Pool(processes=8) as pool:
            pool.starmap(X.extra_fancy_add, [(i, num, num2) for i in self.X])

x = [X(i) for i in range(0,10)]
Y = Y(x)
Y.add_all()
# [i.num for i in Y.X] = [1,2,3,4....] instead of [0,1,2,3,4....] 


x = [X(i) for i in range(0,10)]
Y = Y(x)
Y.fancy_add(10000)
# [i.num for i in Y.X] = [10000, 10001, 10002...] instead of [0,1,2,3,4....] 

x = [X(i) for i in range(0,10)]
Y = Y(x)
Y.extra_fancy_add(1,2)
# [i.num for i in Y.X] = [0.5,1,1.5,2,...] instead of [0,1,2,3,4....]
```

But right now I can't seem to pass the arguments correctly into the pool starmap correctly. I keep getting attribute errrors stating that X has no attribute .add.

Comment: Try `i.add` instead of `X.add`.  You want the element that you are working with from your iterator instead of the entire iterator.

Comment: That doesn't work because i is outside of the list comprehension so it's not defined.